# Provide the header of a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, header

This is a simple homework problem that I don't fully understand. Maybe you guys can help with this one so I can get the others.

For the operations on partially filled arrays of integers below, provide the header of a function (everything but the body). Do not implement the functions.

a. Sort the elements in decreasing order.

Is it wanting some kind of for loop? 
Thanks guys!

Comment: no, it just wants the function declaration...

Comment: What are the partially filled arrays it is talking about?

Comment: I think the fact that you left out much of the problem description is causing confusion. From what you've posted, it sounds like you are just required to write the header, but I'm guessing that's not the case. You should probably post more. If the assignment is to sort an array, then yes, you'll need a loop or two.

Comment: There isn't anymore to the problem other than b, c, d and e which are just parts to answer. For example, b states: **Print all elements, separated by a given string.**

Comment: The exercise is trying to teach you come up with a proper name, and a list of parameters. The name of the function should give readers a clue as to what the function does (`sortDescending`, `printWithSeparator`, etc.) The parameters should enable the function do what needs to be done: if it sorts an array, the function must take an array parameter; if the array is partial, then the function should also get the length of the segment that it is supposed to work on, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it wanting some kind of for loop?

The assignment says that you should not *implement* your function, so no, they do not want to see a loop. All they want is a "signature" of the function - something that details the following three things:

- The name of the function
- The type of the value the function returns (if any; use `void` for "no return value")
- The types and the order of the parameters the function takes (if any).

The syntax for function headers is as follows:

```
float compute ( int, double );
^^^^^ ^^^^^^^ ^ ^^^  ^^^^^^ ^
  |      |    |  |      |   |
  |      |    |  |      |   +- Closing parenthesis (required)
  |      |    |  |      +----- Type of the second argument
  |      |    |  +------------ Type of the first argument
  |      |    +--------------- Opening parenthesis (required)
  |      +-------------------- Function name (must start in a letter)
  +--------------------------- Function's return type
```

Note: This is an example, not an answer to your assignment.

Comment: However, this is puzzling: _a. Sort the elements in decreasing order._

Comment: @CareyGregory That may be a hint to the students to suggest a nice name for their function.

Comment: Actually it will not sort anything - bad answer!

Comment: I think `float compute(int, double)` is intended to be an illustrative example of what they're looking for, not the specific solution. `compute` would be an odd name for a sorting function.

Comment: Wow.One of the greatest answers I've ever seen. It answers not the question only.